# Why is my UIViewController not used as the presentingViewController, although its presentedViewController property gets set?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

Setup on iOS iPad Simulator 5.0.1:

Root controller X, UIViewController **A**, UIViewController **B**

```
A.definesPresentationContext = YES;
// Skipped: set modal presentation props.
[A presentViewController: B, animated: YES, completion: nil];
```

If I check `A.presentedViewController`, the result is **B** - correct.
If I check `B.presentingViewController`, the result is **X**

How is that possible? It also leads to the problem that I don't get informed in **A** if **B** gets dismissed (I'm overriding `dismissViewController:` in **A**).

What do I have to do to make a the presenting controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Methods `[A presentViewController: B, animated: YES, completion: nil];` presents the controller B as a Modal, and all modals are presented from the rootViewController, therefor presentingViewController is X.

If you want to know in A when B is dismissed you will have to fire an NSNotification in B's viewDidDisappear so A can catch that notification

Comment: Is that new in iOS5? I don't remember all modals being presented from root.

Comment: I believe that for iPhone this has always been the same, for iPad everything should work as you say!

Comment: I am on iPad. And there it is now always the root controller. Let's wait for other suggestions, I'm puzzled now.

Comment: Have you tried adding `B.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` and also keep the `A.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

Comment: Yes, then it is working but then the controller is no longer presented modally but as a child controller of the current controller.

Comment: Well.. then you're going to have to write a letter to the IOS dev team ;-) because as far as I know, there is no way to achieve what you want in the way you want.